# The mean weight of 100 bags of rice is 90 pounds and the s.d. is 8 pounds. Bag A weighs 2 s.d. < mean and Bag B weighs 5 pounds > mean. Is A>B?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

The average weight of a set X of 100 bags of rice is 90 pounds , and the standard deviation is 8 pounds. Bag A weighs 2 standard deviations below the average weight and Bag B weighs 5 pounds more than Average.

Choose if quantity A or quantity B is bigger , equal or the information provided is not sufficient:

Quantity A: Difference between weight of Bag A and Bag B
Quantity B: The range of weight of bags in set X

Comment: using formula : mean+3*(sd) - mean - 3*(sd) where sd = standard deviation .. i used this formula but the answer said range cannot be calculated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Without knowing how the data are distributed, how can we determine the range (to calculate quantity B) just from knowing the mean and standard deviation?

So, I feel the answer should be: *Cannot be determined*.

Comment: We cannot calculate quantity B exactly, but can we establish bounds on it? Clearly $B>0$, otherwise the standard deviation would be $0$. Also $B<90\cdot 100$ (99 bags of weight 0, one bag of weight $90\cdot 100$). Using *all* information in the question (weights are positive, mean=90, sd=8, one bag weighs 90-2 sd, another weighs 90+5), how tight could we make the bounds on B? Tight enough to decide if A is bigger?

Comment: Hey your answer is right but cant we determine the range by using the standard deviation graph? And then using formula : mean+3*(sd) - mean - 3*(sd) where sd = standard deviation? i thought like this but your answer is right i still don't get why we can't calculate range?

Comment: The formula you give, mean+3*(sd) - (mean - 3*(sd)) = 6*sd , is not a formula that gives you the range. Consider $\{0,2\}$: mean=1, sd=$\sqrt{2}$, range=2, 6sd$\neq$range. Or consider the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), which has range $[0,1]$ no matter the value of its standard deviation.